# Do foreign entities earning money via US marketplace platform have to pay US taxes?

Tags: united-states, taxes, foreign-income, corporate-earnings, world

I registered a one-person LLC in my country of stay (Taiwan) that I use to receive income from a US-resident online marketplace platform that connects me (offering services) to international customers (namely, Codementor).

The platform had me fill out a W8BEN-E, but they say they will only send it out if the IRS asks for it. When contacting them, they tell me that I need to figure out myself whether and how the company would pay potential taxes in the US.

I have a local accountant and all local taxes taken care. But now I'm worried about taxes in the US, specifically about US sales tax, possibly other? The platform does not give me sufficient information about individual customers to even determine where they are and thus where the capital is sourced, which would probably play a big role in determining this.

I think similar examples of this scenario would include Youtubers, Twitch streamers and others who have a company outside the US, receiving income via these platforms in the US, however the source country being the US as well as many other countries.

Even if I did what everyone recommends, that is seeking a US-based tax professional, I am afraid I would pay a lot of money just ending up with someone unable to help me due to lack of experience in this very specific scenario.

How can I get this question answered?